# I have an array of object like this

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

```
let attributeSet =  [{
    "id": 1,
    "value": 11
  },
  { 
    "id" : 1,
    "value": 12
  },
  {
    "id" : 1,
    "value" : 13
  },
  {
      "id": "2",
      "value" : "Qwerty"
  }
]
```

I want to combine all the value in values like this

```
attributeSet = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": [11, 12, 13]
  },
  {
    "id": 2, 
    "value": "Qwerty"
  }
]
```

I am using two for loops for comparing the ids and then pushing it into an array. Can someone suggest me any better way.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` & inside callback check if the accumulator object have the key same as `id` of the object under iteration. If not then create the key and push value to it

```js
let attributeSet = [{
    "id": 1,
    "value": 11
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": 12
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": 13
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "value": "Qwerty"
  }
]

let newData = attributeSet.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (!acc[curr.id]) {
    acc[curr.id] = {
      id: curr.id,
      value: []
    }
  }
  acc[curr.id].value.push(curr.value)

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(newData))
```